# Java есть ли отличие в использование TreeMap

Tags: java, map, treemap

Возможно вопрос покажется глупым, но хочу узнать есть ли разница в этих записях?

```
Map<Integer, String> map1 = new TreeMap<>(); //1 способ

SortedMap<Integer, String> map2 = new TreeMap<>(); //2 способ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница есть.

В обоих случаях будут созданы такие же точно экземпляры `TreeMap`. Разница заключается в том, какие действия будут доступны через переменные `map1` и `map2`. В случае с `map1` нельзя будет делать действия специфичные для `SortedMap`, т.е. например взятие первого или последнего элемента используя методы типа [firstKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#firstKey()), а используя `map2` это можно сделать.

Компилятор проверяет тип переменной и для `map1` доступны только операции определенные в `Map` несмотря на то, что `map1` содержит ссылку на экземпляр дочернего класса.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, это очень помогло!